# Determine if an e-mail contains a certain number of a specific character

Tags: email, regex, spamassassin

I am hoping to write a SpamAssassin rule that will match if an e-mail contains over `n` of a specific character in the body of the message.  Not necessarily continuous.  So for example, if there were ten total asterisks in a message, then match the rule.

I know how to write a rule if there are ten continuous asterisks, like so:

```
body TEN_ASTERISKS /(**********)/
score TEN_ASTERISKS 0.5
describe TEN_ASTERISKS Message body contains ten asterisks.
```

How would I re-write the rule to match on ten total asterisks, not necessarily in a row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The above rule is malformed and will not work.

[SpamAssassin rules](https://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/WritingRules) are [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), so you merely need to escape those:

```
body TEN_ASTERISKS /\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*/
score TEN_ASTERISKS 0.5
describe TEN_ASTERISKS Message body contains ten asterisks.
```

Also, the parentheses are unnecessary.  They form a [capture group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) that is stored in memory, which (assuming you see a lot of asterisk-ridden mail) could take a toll on your server.

(You can also do `body TEN_ASTERISKS /\*{10}/` but I wanted to make a simpler example.  Regular expressions are very powerful.)

---

To match ten separate asterisks, you need `tflags multiple`:

```
body     __HAS_ASTERISK  /\*/
tflags   __HAS_ASTERISK  multiple maxhits=11
meta     TEN_ASTERISKS   __HAS_ASTERISK > 10
score    TEN_ASTERISKS   0.5
describe TEN_ASTERISKS   Message body contains ten asterisks.
```

The `maxhits=11` piece is an optimization.  It tells SpamAssassin to stop counting (`tflags multiple` is expensive to run).

Comment: I was not aware of `tflags`, that is exactly what I was looking for!  One step closer to eliminating unsolicited junk spam... as far as the parenthesis go, would they be redundant if used like `/(\*)/`??  I typically have some parenthesis in my basic rules that are simply looking for certain keywords, like Viagra, etc. that are all grouped together.  For example `/(viagra|cialis)/i`, would that be equivalent to `/viagra|cialis/i` in that case?

Comment: `/(\*)/` would capture the asterisk for future use, which you do not have, so it does nothing. `/(A|B)/i` is identical to `/A|B/i` although `/(A|B)C/i` differs from `/A|BC/i` in that the latter does not match "AC". `/(?:A|B)C/i` is a non-capturing regex that is slightly more efficient. `/(A|B)C\1/i` would match "aCA" but not "ACB". This is all basic regular expression stuff, not SpamAssassin-specific, so perhaps try a [regex tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) to start.

Comment: Great, thank you for the clarification, as well as the additional resource.  I will check it out, regular expressions have always been difficult for me to fully comprehend!

Comment: [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/) is a nice live experimentation resource as well.  Its developer is great and has taken lots of feedback and the interface is really slick.

Comment: I had bookmarked regexpal.com before for testing regular expressions, but it is not that great.  Regex 101 looks like it will be a really good tool for testing new regular expressions before I add them to spam assassin :)  thanks again!